# What is "bruised suavity"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Excerpted from [theatlantic.com](http://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2013/06/when-men-lost-their-charm/309303/):

> If one were to recast The Rockford Files, as Universal Pictures is intending to do, would the Frat Pack actor Vince Vaughn seem the wisest choice to play Jim Rockford, the character James Garner inhabited with such sly intelligence and **bruised suavity**? Universal apparently thinks so.

I know what bruised and suavity mean individually but not combined, what does it mean?

Comment: If you changed *suavity* to *ego*, would you get what a *bruised ego* is? Of course, it doesn't mean the same thing as the original *bruised suavity*, but the *bruised* is being used identically in both cases, and the same metaphor applies. Since you know what *suavity* is, if you can understand *bruised ego*, then *bruised suavity* should be clear enough.

Comment: @DanBron I think *bruised ego* means an ego which is harmed in some way? So *bruised suavity* means a somewhat harmed suavity?

Comment: Bingo. You got it.

Comment: @DanBron But it's still quite strange to me, for example, if I say a person has bruised suavity, what traits might he have?

Comment: A suavity, but an imperfect one. A damaged, and so not *quite* credible slickness. Go to YouTube and see if you can watch an old episode of the Rockford Files (it was an entertaining show, especially if you're familiar with the earlier detective or noir genres it was subverting). You'll see immediately what this quote is talking about. Or maybe check out [TVtropes.com's description of the Rockford Files](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/TheRockfordFiles).

Comment: @DanBron I'll upvote your answer if you post it.

Comment: @DanBron I will, too. Rockford Files was one of my favorites when I was a kid. He was antithetical to the earlier detectives who were usually dishing it out. He was almost always on the receiving end, but he still solved his cases.